# Ubuntu 12.04 and 2560x1600 display

Tags: display, resolution

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

First let me give you has much information as possible.
I own a Dell E4310 and a monitor U3011, I was using ubuntu 11.10 I believe and everything was working without to much problem.
I just installed 12.04 64bit and... I have no image anymore.

When I boot from the Live CD, it display and can reach the 2560x1600 native resolution.
One the installation done, if I disable the laptop display to keep only the 30" display, I can only reach 1920x1200.
Any resolution above will give me a black screen (only deleting the monitors.xml) will allow me to recover.

I believe the graphic card in the laptop is an Intel HD3000

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What is the output of `xrandr -q` ?

Also running `xrand --auto` could work.